# WebRequest.Create hangs forever

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

This code is hanging forever, not on the retrieval of the request/response stream, but in WebRequest's creation:

```
public static void PublishFileList(List<string> files, string url) {
    string content = files.Aggregate<string>((res, file) => res+file+"\n");
    byte[] contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    Console.WriteLine(content);
    request.GetRequestStream().Write(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
    request.GetRequestStream().Close();
    request.GetResponse().Close();
}
```

The `WriteLine` call is never executed. This is being called with a valid URL:

```
PublishFileList(files, "http://example.com/update");
```

I have no idea of a cause for this. I've used WebRequests before, and this never happened to me (nor anyone else, apparently, because googling gave no results)

EDIT:

Here's the call stack:

```
[Managed to Native Transition] in 
System.Net.WinHttpWebProxyBuilder.BuildInternal () in 
System.Net.WebProxyDataBuilder.Build () in 
System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine.GetWebProxyData () in 
System.Net.WebProxy.UnsafeUpdateFromRegistry () in 
System.Net.WebProxy..ctor (enableAutoproxy=true) in 
System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal..ctor (section={System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySection}) in 
System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal.GetSection () in 
System.Net.WebRequest.get_InternalDefaultWebProxy () in 
System.Net.HttpWebRequest..ctor (uri={System.Uri}, servicePoint=(null)) in 
System.Net.HttpRequestCreator.Create (Uri={System.Uri}) in 
System.Net.WebRequest.Create (requestUri={System.Uri}, useUriBase=false) in 
System.Net.WebRequest.Create (requestUriString="http://example.com/update") in 
Updater.MainClass.PublishFileList (files=Cannot evaluate expression because the thread is stopped in native code., url="http://example.com/update") in <redacted>
```

Comment: Pause the debugger when it's hung & look at the call stack.

Comment: It may be an IE issue.  Try rebooting.  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_WinHttpWebProxyDataBuilder.cs#664dd68da6326c93

Comment: @SLaks Be right back, then.

Comment: @SLaks It seems to be gone now...